# Python BigQuery Exception: Cannot output HOUR partitioned data in LegacySQL

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery, pyarrow

I tried to upload a python dataframe to hourly partitioned table in bigquery.

The table is not created at bigquery, I tried to use this code to create table and upload dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
import datetime

a = ['A','B','C']
b = [0,1,0]
c = [datetime.datetime(2020,4,2,1,2,0),datetime.datetime(2020,4,2,2,0,0),datetime.datetime(2020,4,2,3,0,0)]
dic = {'Name':a, 'Pos':b, 'Time':c}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)     
partition_date_column = 'Time'
out_bq_name = 'test_hour'
proj = my_proj
dataset = my_dataset
client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
table_id = '.'.join([proj,dataset,out_bq_name])
job_config.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(type_ = 'HOUR',
                field=partition_date_column)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df,table_id,job_config = job_config, location = 'US')
job.result()
```

Return:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Cannot output HOUR partitioned data in LegacySQL
```

Did I use something like LegacySQL?

When I set `TimePartitioning(type_='DAY')`, my code worked.

Package Version:

```
pandas 1.0.5
pyarrow 0.17.1
google-cloud-bigquery 1.25.0
```

Python: 3.6.10

How to upload dataframe to bigquery to hourly partitioned table?

Comment: Check this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617422/can-one-have-hourly-partitions-in-a-bigquery-table

Comment: According to the documentation [lines](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#changing_from_the_default_dialect) *StandardSQL*  is a default dialect for Python client library but not the legacy one. What would happen if you manually enforce it to Standard SQL then: `bigquery.LoadJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=False)`?

Comment: Return 400 error too.

Comment: Do you have the same error when you manually create a table in Bigquery?